# Split Large Text file into smaller files parts according to file content

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have the following file: ( that contain info from dmesg )

```
more /tmp/file.txt

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ worker01.miss.com @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
[Fri Jan  8 06:29:09 2021] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[Fri Jan  8 06:29:09 2021] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[Fri Jan  8 06:29:09 2021] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
.
.
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ worker02.miss.com @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
[Fri Jan  8 06:29:09 2021] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[Fri Jan  8 06:29:09 2021] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[Fri Jan  8 06:29:09 2021] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
.
.
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ worker03.miss.com @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
[Fri Jan  8 06:29:09 2021] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[Fri Jan  8 06:29:09 2021] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[Fri Jan  8 06:29:09 2021] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
.
.
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ worker04.miss.com @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
[Fri Jan  8 06:29:09 2021] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[Fri Jan  8 06:29:09 2021] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[Fri Jan  8 06:29:09 2021] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
.
.
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ worker05.miss.com @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
[Fri Jan  8 06:29:09 2021] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[Fri Jan  8 06:29:09 2021] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[Fri Jan  8 06:29:09 2021] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
.
.
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ worker06.miss.com @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
[Fri Jan  8 06:29:09 2021] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[Fri Jan  8 06:29:09 2021] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[Fri Jan  8 06:29:09 2021] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
.
.
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ worker07.miss.com @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
[Fri Jan  8 06:29:09 2021] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[Fri Jan  8 06:29:09 2021] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[Fri Jan  8 06:29:09 2021] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
.
.
```

and we want to create files as

```
worker01.miss.com.txt
worker02.miss.com.txt
worker03.miss.com.txt
.
.
.
```

when for example `worker01.miss.com.txt` file , will include the content

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ worker01.miss.com @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
[Fri Jan  8 06:29:09 2021] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[Fri Jan  8 06:29:09 2021] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[Fri Jan  8 06:29:09 2021] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
.
.
```

and when for example `worker02.miss.com.txt` will include the content

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ worker02.miss.com @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
[Fri Jan  8 06:29:09 2021] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[Fri Jan  8 06:29:09 2021] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[Fri Jan  8 06:29:09 2021] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
.
.
```

and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
$ awk '/^@/ {close(dmesg_info); dmesg_info=$2".txt"} {print > dmesg_info}' input_file
$ cat worker01.miss.com.txt
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ worker01.miss.com @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
[Fri Jan  8 06:29:09 2021] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[Fri Jan  8 06:29:09 2021] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[Fri Jan  8 06:29:09 2021] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
.
.
$ cat worker02.miss.com.txt
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ worker02.miss.com @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
[Fri Jan  8 06:29:09 2021] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[Fri Jan  8 06:29:09 2021] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[Fri Jan  8 06:29:09 2021] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
.
.
```

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks :)